# Breaking Down Standard Deviation Into Smaller Units

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation

I have calculated my standard deviation in winnings by session of playing poker, with each session being an average of X hours. Since everything in the poker world is discussed in terms of standard deviation per hour, does it make sense to say my standard deviation per hour is the standard deviation per session divided by the average session length in hours?

In other words, my standard deviation in winnings per session is 1000, but my average session is 10 hours, so my standard deviation per hour is 100.

Seems simple enough, but this feels somewhat wrong to me, because it seems to considerably "dull out" the expected deviations and assume a degree of consistency that isn't there.

Comment: Standard deviation of what?

Comment: @PeterFlom Standard deviation of winnings by session, I have edited OP

Comment: Although it makes sense to do that division, the answer likely is wrong.  One would expect your winnings to be positively correlated over time (due to periods in which the opponents do not change, your degree of mental acuity, and so on).  This affects the relationship between the SD within one hour and the SD within longer (or shorter) time periods.  Because standard theories of time series analysis cope explicitly with this issue, I have added the [tag:time-series] tag to your post.